# How to use the result of a command in another command in bash?

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to replace the 10th line of my Gruntfile.js by lines extracted from finaltest.txt in every iteration of the loop. However, after the following code what happens is in my Gruntfile.js the 10th line is getting replaced by the string `$x` and NOT the value it contains. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash 

for i in {1..354}
do
    x=`sed -n '$ip' finaltest.txt`
    sed -i '10s/.*/$x/' Gruntfile.js
    grunt

done
```

Also, `grunt` command is to run the `Gruntfile.js`. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: The problem of $x has been solved in the answer given below,`sed -i "10s~.*~$x~" Gruntfile.js`.

However, the only part left is, I want lines 1,2,3,4,etc like `1p,2p,3p,4p,etc` of finaltest.txt to replace the 10th line of Gruntfile.js. But

```
x=`sed -n '$ip' finaltest.txt
```

does not work properly for $i, it gives an error. I also tried `"$(i)p"` but still nothing. What should I modify?

Comment: Use double quotes: `sed -i "10s/.*/$x" Gruntfile.js`

Comment: Doesn't help. says `sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to \`s'
`

Comment: @kaushaya: does the output of `x` contains by any chance a slash?

Comment: example x= `'./newcss/354.css':'./4dlife/tools/experiments/tests/test_resources_provider.html'`

Answer (score 1):

Use this sed command:

```
sed -i "10s~.*~$x~" Gruntfile.js
```

- Use double quotes for shell to allow expanding `$x`
- Use alternate regex delimiter `~` because your `$x` value contains `/` in it.

---

**EDIT:** Based on your edited question. Your first part also needs to be double quoted here:

```
x=$(sed "$iq;d" finaltest.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks this part worked! Look at the command stored by x. I want every line which should be replaced like $1p,$2p, etc and I wrote it like &ip however the output is just p. How to solve it?

Comment: Still the same, no output.

Comment: These comments like `does not work` or `no output` are of no use. How can someone interpret your problem with that information. I can only test these commands separately and they're working fine. You must also understand my original answer has already solved your problem and you have added an additional question (not generally encouraged on SO)

Comment: You must provide a sample of both files `finaltest.txt` and `Gruntfile.js` in question and also show your expected output in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71280/discussion-between-kaushaya-and-anubhava).

Comment: If it worked out you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.